# Using MySQL socket with Orange3

Tags: python, orange

The Orange3 "SQL Table" Widget allows to connect to a MSSQL server, but is it possible to use it with a local MySQL installation? I would like to make use of a MySQL socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql is not supported. See https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/3565 and linked issues.

Comment: Is anyone working on this? What would be needed to have support for MySQL? It seems to me that this should be quite straight forward to implement. At least for some simple data retrieval. Would a new Widget be the way to go?

Comment: I am not aware of anyone that is trying to implement this. It shouldn't be too complex; maybe you would not even need a new widget. The hard part is to make it stable and test it well.