# How do you setup a MySQL connection for Orange?

Tags: mysql, orange

Has anyone ever setup a SQL connection for Orange? The API (https://docs.biolab.si//3/data-mining-library/reference/data.sql.html) does not provide any decent examples, from my read of things. If you could point me to a link or show me an example connection object in Python, that would be great. I am trying to do some CN2 classification on a table in my MySQL database.

Comment: To clarify, I need to do this in a script, not the GUI.

Comment: For Orange __v2.7.6__, see [this](https://orange.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/rst/Orange.data.sql.html)

Comment: Based on [this](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/pull/3954), support for mysql in orange3 is not yet available

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MySQL socket with Orange3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866891/using-mysql-socket-with-orange3)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using a ODBC connector:

```
from pyodbc import connect

connector = connect('Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};'
                 'Server=server name or IP;'
                 'Database=database name;'
                 'UID=User;'
                 'PWD=password;')
cursor = connector.cursor() # Creation of the cursor for data swept.

# Execution of the SQL Query.
cursor.execute("SELECT id, data1, data2 FROM table1")

# All data of "table1" are saved in "data".
data = cursor.fetchall()
```